# Binary DenseNet 121 Classifier only predicting positive with probability >0.5

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, classification, conv-neural-network

I borrowed code from this github repo for training of a DenseNet-121 [https://github.com/gaetandi/cheXpert/blob/master/cheXpert_final.ipynb][1]

The github code is for 14 class classification on the CheXpert chest X-ray dataset. I've revised it for binary classification.

```
# initialize and load the model
pathModel = "/ds2/images/model_ones_2epoch_densenet.tar"#"m-epoch0-07032019-213933.pth.tar"
```

I initialize the 14 class model so I can use the pretrained weights:

```
model = DenseNet121(nnClassCount).cuda()

model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()
modelCheckpoint = torch.load(pathModel)
model.load_state_dict(modelCheckpoint['state_dict'])
```

And then convert to binary classification:

```
nnClassCount = 1
model.module.densenet121.classifier = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1024, nnClassCount), 
    nn.Sigmoid()
).cuda()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()
```

And then train via:

```
batch, losst, losse = CheXpertTrainer.train(model, dataLoaderTrain, dataLoaderVal, nnClassCount, 100, timestampLaunch, checkpoint = None, weight_path = weight_path)
```

My training data is laid out in a 2 column csv with column headers ('Path' and 'Class-Positive'), with path locations in the first column and 0 or 1 in the second column. I used oversampling when compiling the training list so paths in the csv are roughly a 50/50 split between 0's and 1's...shuffled.

I use livelossplot to monitor training/validation loss and accuracy. My loss plots look as expected but accuracy plots are flatlined around 0.5 (which makes sense given the 50/50 data if the net is saying its 100% positive or negative). I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong in how I'm doing predictions, but maybe something in the training is incorrect.

For predictions and probabilities I'm running:

```
 varOutput = model(varInput)
    _, preds = torch.max(varOutput, 1)
    print('varshape: ',varOutput.shape)
    probs = torch.sigmoid(varOutput)
```

***My issue: preds are all coming out as 0 and probs all above 0.5 ***

Here is the initial code from github:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
import csv
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as tfunc
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data.dataset import random_split
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau
from PIL import Image
import torch.nn.functional as func

from sklearn.metrics.ranking import roc_auc_score
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
import random

use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()
# Paths to the files with training, and validation sets.
# Each file contains pairs (path to image, output vector)
pathFileTrain = '../CheXpert-v1.0-small/train.csv'
pathFileValid = '../CheXpert-v1.0-small/valid.csv'

# Neural network parameters:
nnIsTrained = False                 #pre-trained using ImageNet
nnClassCount = 14                   #dimension of the output

# Training settings: batch size, maximum number of epochs
trBatchSize = 64
trMaxEpoch = 3

# Parameters related to image transforms: size of the down-scaled image, cropped image
imgtransResize = (320, 320)
imgtransCrop = 224

# Class names
class_names = ['No Finding', 'Enlarged Cardiomediastinum', 'Cardiomegaly', 'Lung Opacity', 
               'Lung Lesion', 'Edema', 'Consolidation', 'Pneumonia', 'Atelectasis', 'Pneumothorax', 
               'Pleural Effusion', 'Pleural Other', 'Fracture', 'Support Devices']
class CheXpertDataSet(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_list_file, transform=None, policy="ones"):
        """
        image_list_file: path to the file containing images with corresponding labels.
        transform: optional transform to be applied on a sample.
        Upolicy: name the policy with regard to the uncertain labels
        """
        image_names = []
        labels = []

        with open(image_list_file, "r") as f:
            csvReader = csv.reader(f)
            next(csvReader, None)
            k=0
            for line in csvReader:
                k+=1
                image_name= line[0]
                label = line[5:]

                for i in range(14):
                    if label[i]:
                        a = float(label[i])
                        if a == 1:
                            label[i] = 1
                        elif a == -1:
                            if policy == "ones":
                                label[i] = 1
                            elif policy == "zeroes":
                                label[i] = 0
                            else:
                                label[i] = 0
                        else:
                            label[i] = 0
                    else:
                        label[i] = 0

                image_names.append('../' + image_name)
                labels.append(label)

        self.image_names = image_names
        self.labels = labels
        self.transform = transform

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Take the index of item and returns the image and its labels"""

        image_name = self.image_names[index]
        image = Image.open(image_name).convert('RGB')
        label = self.labels[index]
        if self.transform is not None:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image, torch.FloatTensor(label)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_names)
#TRANSFORM DATA

normalize = transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
transformList = []
#transformList.append(transforms.Resize(imgtransCrop))
transformList.append(transforms.RandomResizedCrop(imgtransCrop))
transformList.append(transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip())
transformList.append(transforms.ToTensor())
transformList.append(normalize)      
transformSequence=transforms.Compose(transformList)
#LOAD DATASET

dataset = CheXpertDataSet(pathFileTrain ,transformSequence, policy="ones")
datasetTest, datasetTrain = random_split(dataset, [500, len(dataset) - 500])
datasetValid = CheXpertDataSet(pathFileValid, transformSequence)            
#Problèmes de l'overlapping de patients et du transform identique ?

dataLoaderTrain = DataLoader(dataset=datasetTrain, batch_size=trBatchSize, shuffle=True,  num_workers=24, pin_memory=True)
dataLoaderVal = DataLoader(dataset=datasetValid, batch_size=trBatchSize, shuffle=False, num_workers=24, pin_memory=True)
dataLoaderTest = DataLoader(dataset=datasetTest, num_workers=24, pin_memory=True)
class CheXpertTrainer():

    def train (model, dataLoaderTrain, dataLoaderVal, nnClassCount, trMaxEpoch, launchTimestamp, checkpoint):

        #SETTINGS: OPTIMIZER & SCHEDULER
        optimizer = optim.Adam (model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08, weight_decay=1e-5)

        #SETTINGS: LOSS
        loss = torch.nn.BCELoss(size_average = True)

        #LOAD CHECKPOINT 
        if checkpoint != None and use_gpu:
            modelCheckpoint = torch.load(checkpoint)
            model.load_state_dict(modelCheckpoint['state_dict'])
            optimizer.load_state_dict(modelCheckpoint['optimizer'])


        #TRAIN THE NETWORK
        lossMIN = 100000

        for epochID in range(0, trMaxEpoch):

            timestampTime = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
            timestampDate = time.strftime("%d%m%Y")
            timestampSTART = timestampDate + '-' + timestampTime

            batchs, losst, losse = CheXpertTrainer.epochTrain(model, dataLoaderTrain, optimizer, trMaxEpoch, nnClassCount, loss)
            lossVal = CheXpertTrainer.epochVal(model, dataLoaderVal, optimizer, trMaxEpoch, nnClassCount, loss)


            timestampTime = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
            timestampDate = time.strftime("%d%m%Y")
            timestampEND = timestampDate + '-' + timestampTime

            if lossVal < lossMIN:
                lossMIN = lossVal    
                torch.save({'epoch': epochID + 1, 'state_dict': model.state_dict(), 'best_loss': lossMIN, 'optimizer' : optimizer.state_dict()}, 'm-epoch'+str(epochID)+'-' + launchTimestamp + '.pth.tar')
                print ('Epoch [' + str(epochID + 1) + '] [save] [' + timestampEND + '] loss= ' + str(lossVal))
            else:
                print ('Epoch [' + str(epochID + 1) + '] [----] [' + timestampEND + '] loss= ' + str(lossVal))

        return batchs, losst, losse        
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    def epochTrain(model, dataLoader, optimizer, epochMax, classCount, loss):

        batch = []
        losstrain = []
        losseval = []

        model.train()

        for batchID, (varInput, target) in enumerate(dataLoaderTrain):

            varTarget = target.cuda(non_blocking = True)

            #varTarget = target.cuda()         


            varOutput = model(varInput)
            lossvalue = loss(varOutput, varTarget)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            lossvalue.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            l = lossvalue.item()
            losstrain.append(l)

            if batchID%35==0:
                print(batchID//35, "% batches computed")
                #Fill three arrays to see the evolution of the loss


                batch.append(batchID)

                le = CheXpertTrainer.epochVal(model, dataLoaderVal, optimizer, trMaxEpoch, nnClassCount, loss).item()
                losseval.append(le)

                print(batchID)
                print(l)
                print(le)

        return batch, losstrain, losseval

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    def epochVal(model, dataLoader, optimizer, epochMax, classCount, loss):

        model.eval()

        lossVal = 0
        lossValNorm = 0

        with torch.no_grad():
            for i, (varInput, target) in enumerate(dataLoaderVal):

                target = target.cuda(non_blocking = True)
                varOutput = model(varInput)

                losstensor = loss(varOutput, target)
                lossVal += losstensor
                lossValNorm += 1

        outLoss = lossVal / lossValNorm
        return outLoss


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

    #---- Computes area under ROC curve 
    #---- dataGT - ground truth data
    #---- dataPRED - predicted data
    #---- classCount - number of classes

    def computeAUROC (dataGT, dataPRED, classCount):

        outAUROC = []

        datanpGT = dataGT.cpu().numpy()
        datanpPRED = dataPRED.cpu().numpy()

        for i in range(classCount):
            try:
                outAUROC.append(roc_auc_score(datanpGT[:, i], datanpPRED[:, i]))
            except ValueError:
                pass
        return outAUROC


    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 


    def test(model, dataLoaderTest, nnClassCount, checkpoint, class_names):   

        cudnn.benchmark = True

        if checkpoint != None and use_gpu:
            modelCheckpoint = torch.load(checkpoint)
            model.load_state_dict(modelCheckpoint['state_dict'])

        if use_gpu:
            outGT = torch.FloatTensor().cuda()
            outPRED = torch.FloatTensor().cuda()
        else:
            outGT = torch.FloatTensor()
            outPRED = torch.FloatTensor()

        model.eval()

        with torch.no_grad():
            for i, (input, target) in enumerate(dataLoaderTest):

                target = target.cuda()
                outGT = torch.cat((outGT, target), 0).cuda()

                bs, c, h, w = input.size()
                varInput = input.view(-1, c, h, w)

                out = model(varInput)
                outPRED = torch.cat((outPRED, out), 0)
        aurocIndividual = CheXpertTrainer.computeAUROC(outGT, outPRED, nnClassCount)
        aurocMean = np.array(aurocIndividual).mean()

        print ('AUROC mean ', aurocMean)

        for i in range (0, len(aurocIndividual)):
            print (class_names[i], ' ', aurocIndividual[i])

        return outGT, outPRED
class DenseNet121(nn.Module):
    """Model modified.
    The architecture of our model is the same as standard DenseNet121
    except the classifier layer which has an additional sigmoid function.
    """
    def __init__(self, out_size):
        super(DenseNet121, self).__init__()
        self.densenet121 = torchvision.models.densenet121(pretrained=True)
        num_ftrs = self.densenet121.classifier.in_features
        self.densenet121.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(num_ftrs, out_size),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.densenet121(x)
        return x
# initialize and load the model
model = DenseNet121(nnClassCount).cuda()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()
timestampTime = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
timestampDate = time.strftime("%d%m%Y")
timestampLaunch = timestampDate + '-' + timestampTime

batch, losst, losse = CheXpertTrainer.train(model, dataLoaderTrain, dataLoaderVal, nnClassCount, trMaxEpoch, timestampLaunch, checkpoint = None)
print("Model trained")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have adapted the training correctly for the binary classification, but the prediction wasn't, as you are still trying it as if it were a multi-class prediction.

The output of your model (`varOutput`) has the size *(batch_size, 1)*, since there is only one class. The maximum across that dimension will always be 0, since that is the only class available, there is no separate class for 1.

This single class represents both cases (0 and 1), so you can consider it is a the probability of it being positive (1). To get the distinct value of either 0 or 1, you simply use a threshold of 0.5, so everything below that receives the class 0 and above that 1. This can be easily done with [`torch.round`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.round).

But you also have another problem, you're applying the sigmoid function twice in a row, once in the classifier `nn.Sigmoid()` and then afterwards again `torch.sigmoid(varOutput)`. That is problematic, because *sigmoid(0) = 0.5*, hence all your probabilities are over 0.5.

The output of your model are already the probabilities, the only thing left is to round them:

```py
probs = model(varInput)
# The .squeeze(1) is to get rid of the singular class dimension
preds = torch.round(probs).squeeze(1)
```